# Writing If Statements in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel

I want to do in If then statement using three sheets.  Something Like this, If (Cell=Accepted, then this cell is eual to sheet 1, if false then leave blank).

Comment: Try to describe more of what you are trying to achieve, why should the Accepted cell equal sheet 1, what value or condition from sheet1?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you're putting this into `Sheet3` cell `A1`, then the following will check `Sheet2` cell `A1` for the value "Accepted" and put the value of `Sheet1` cell `A1` into the cell, otherwise it will leave it blank.

```
=if(Sheet2!A1="Accepted",Sheet1!A1,"")
```

Comment: hi user192213, welcome to SO! Please don't forget to accept this as an answer - and upvote the answer if it helped you!

Comment: Ok another question to that, if =if(Sheet2!A1="Accepted",Sheet1!A1,""), instead of accepted how would I type if I need it to be date only instead of Accepted and it it's a date it goes to sheet 2 and if it's not a date it goes to sheet 3? so if(sheet2!A1="some date",Sheet1!A1,"")

Comment: There's not a function to do that directly in Excel, but there are [some ways to "fake" it](http://www.ozgrid.com/forum/showthread.php?t=50541).  Try those, or do some google searches for other methods.  If you're still not getting it, try a new question here, but be sure to detail what you've tried and where it's not working.

Comment: I've manipulated it by if it's = "NA" then put in sheet 3 and if <> "NA" then put on sheet 2, but now ran into issue that when using <> it puts 0 in when data is blank?  Anyway to fix this?  Here's the acutal code... =IF('Master Intake Tracker'!K7 <>"NA",'Master Intake Tracker'!A7,"")

Comment: This doesn't work....because if the cell is blank then the cell <> "NA" so the data is showing up....don't want that either....ugh!

Comment: You will find more help with this if you rewrite what you're doing as a new question, rather than comments.  Since you accepted an answer, and because the question was closed, no one else is likely to look at this in a timely manner.